# subnavigation css- display on hovering position

Tags: html, css

I am doing navigation bar with subnav, the result I get from below code is when I hover main link , the submenu does not come right under the main link . If you click products link you could see it comes under home link, where I want product submenu to be displayed  under product link and aligned just under where p in products starts.
2.Also can someone tell me why the link which has submenu creates space between next link. in this example, there is a space between home and products but no space between contact us and payment. how to ignore the space between link irrespective of of main menu holding submenu or not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN" dir="ltr">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css" type="text/css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="navi.css" type="text/css"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="new  2.html">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Printing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Scanning</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="sidebarright.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="sidebarright.html">Payment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.navigation{ width:400px;margin:0; padding:0;}
.navigation li{
    display:inline; 
}

.navigation li a{
    color:white;
    padding:.2em 1em;
    background-color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:black; 
    border-right:1px white solid;
}

.navigation li a:hover{background-color:#eee;border-top:2px solid #ddd;color:#333;}
.navigation li ul {
    position: absolute; 
    display: none;
    width: inherit;

 }
.navigation li:hover ul {
    display:block; 
    width:100px;
    margin: 4px 0 0 -20px;  
}
.navigation li:hover ul li{
    position: relative;       
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}  
.navigation li:hover ul li a{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    color:red; 
    padding:.2em 1em;
    background-color:#eee; 
    border-bottom:thin black solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your li, then give `left` value for the submenu, so that the submenu comes under the correct parent menu.

Also if you don't want spaces between the menu items, use `float:left` on `li` instead of `display:inline`. You can still see a small white space, that is the `border-right` you've added on `.navigation li a`

https://jsfiddle.net/hd23dhab/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add these changes to your css:

```
.navigation {
    /* width: 400px; */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navigation li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
    left: -20px;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de00z7z8/2/)